# All real number solutions of equation $\log_{2011}(2010x) = \log_{2010}(2011x)$ are in certain interval. Which one is it?

Tags: logarithms

This task has to be done with no calculator, but I don't have basic idea how to start. Can someone give me advice, I know this is pretty easy but I need direction for particularly this one?
EDIT: I do it like this 
$$\log_{2011}(2010x) = \log_{2010}(2011x)$$
$${\ln{2010x}\over\ln2011}={\ln{2011x}\over\ln2010}$$
$${{\ln{2010} + \ln{x}}\over\ln2011}={\ln{2011} + \ln{x}\over\ln2010}$$
$$\ln^2{2010} + \ln{x}(\ln2010) = \ln^2{2011} + \ln{x}(\ln2011)$$
$$\ln^2{2010} - \ln^2{2011} -\ln{x}(\ln{2011} - \ln{2010}) = 0 $$
$$(\ln{2011} - \ln{2010})(\ln{2011} + \ln{2010} - \ln{x}) = 0$$
$$\ln{(2010 * 2011)\over x} = \ln{1}$$
$$x = 2010 * 2011$$
What am I doing wrong here?
And also, how to even get solution (which is $x\in (0,{1\over 2011}])$

Answer (score 5):

*Hint:* $$\log_{2011}(2010x) = \frac{\ln 2010 + \ln x}{\ln 2011}$$ Rewrite $\log_{2010}(2011x)$ similarly and solve for $\ln x$.

Comment: I just get  that $ x = 2010*2011$ but it is not the answer I'm looking for. Could you please provide further steps?

Comment: @GreatDuke: If you have any secret conditions on which kind of answer you're looking for, you need to tell what they are. This answer looks like it solves your problem completely.

Comment: @GreatDuke: Oh, and you must have dropped a sign somewhere -- I get $x=\frac1{2010\cdot 2011}$.

Comment: Solution booklet says that interval is $(0,{1 \over 2011}]$

Comment: @GreatDuke: That is one of infinitely many intervals that all contain the solution. Other options would be, for example, $(0,1)$ or $[\frac{1}{2010\cdot 2011},\frac{2}{2010\cdot 2011})$.

Comment: Can someone please look at my edit, I desperately need solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

$ x=\frac{1}{2010 \times2011}$
Just use normal properties of log
like

1) first change the base of every log to e

2) expand $ln2010x$ and $ln 2011x $ using property $ lnab=lna + lnb $

3) solve for x